# Compare values of one column of dataframe in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, if-statement

I have 2 dataframes. df1 is

```
   DATE
2020-05-20
2020-05-21
```

and df2 is

```
ID    NAME    DATE
1     abc     2020-05-20
2     bcd     2020-05-20
3     ggg     2020-05-25
4     jhg     2020-05-26
```

I want to compare the values of df1 with df2, for eg: taking first value of df1 i.e 2020-05-20 and find it in df2 and filter it and show output and subset the filtered rows.
My code is

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    x = row['DATE']
    if x == df2['DATE']:
        print('Found')
        new = df2[df2['DATE'] == x]
        print(new)
    else:
        print('Not Found')
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a series is ambigious. Use a.empty,a.bool(),a.item(),a.any()
```

Comment: Please post full error stack trace, for this question and in the future. Will greatly help us help you

Comment: Please post the *full* stack trace - including the line giving the error. Also *use copy-paste* why type it by hand?

Comment: Please post the expected output.

Comment: True.But Actually i was not able to copy it.Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x == df2['DATE']` is a `pd.Series` (of Booleans), not a single value. You have to reduce that to a single Boolean value in order to evaluate that in a condition.

You can either use [`.any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) or [`.all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html) depeding on what you need. I assumed you need `.any()` here.

```
for index,row in df1.iterrows():
    x = row['DATE']
    if (x == df2['DATE']).any():
        print('Found')
        new = df2[df2['DATE'] == x]
        print(new)
    else:
        print('Not Found')
```

Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32618273/for-every-row-in-pandas-dataframe-determine-if-a-column-value-exists-in-another) for a pure pandas solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

you can create one extra column in df1 and use np.where to fill it.

```
import numpy as np
df1['Match'] = np.where(df1.DATE.isin(df2.DATE),'Found', 'Not Found')
```

Answer (score 0):

this can also be done as a `merge` which I think makes it a bit clearer as it's only one line with no branching. You can also add the `validate` parameter to make sure that each key is unique in either the left of right dataset,

```py
import pandas

df1 = pandas.DataFrame(['2020-05-20', '2020-05-21'], columns=['DATE'])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame({'Name': ['abc', 'bcd', 'ggg', 'jgh'], 
                        'DATE': ['2020-05-20', '2020-05-20', '2020-05-25', '2020-05-26']})

df3 = df1.merge(right=df2, on='DATE', how='left')
```